# Threads in a vector can't be joined

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector, stdthread

I want to store a collection of threads in a vector, and join them all before exiting my program. I receive the following error when trying to join the first thread no matter how many I place in the collection:

```
system_error: thread::join failed: No such process
```

Here is some simple code that demonstrates my issue:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::thread;
using std::mem_fn;

int main()
{
  vector<thread> threads(1);
  threads.push_back(thread([]{ cout << "Hello" << endl; }));
  for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), mem_fn(&thread::join));

  // also tried --> for(thread &t : threads) t.join()
}
```

And I'm building it using the following (tried clang++ 4.2.1 and g++ 5.3.1):

```
g++ -o src/thread_test.o -c -std=c++14 src/thread_test.cpp -pthread
g++ -o thread_test src/thread_test.o -pthread
```

I see lots of examples doing just this around the internet. Did something change in the contract of `<thread>` or `<vector>` that's rendered these examples defunct?

NOTE: As an aside for future readers, I ended up adding the (1) constructor argument after trying `{}` assignment, which fails due to a private copy constructor. In trying to avoid the copy constructor I ended up allocating uninitialized threads -- careless mistake.

Comment: Please use the `-pthread` compiler flags for both compiling and linking stage, rather than linking `-lpthread`.

Comment: I'm using scons, so it formats my library arguments for me. It actually works without either -pthread or -lpthread and I had added it just to make sure I wasn't missing some implementation detail during my troubles. So 1) i think the compiler is adding those flags for me silently, and 2) why is the nonstandard lib include preferable?

Comment: `-lpthread` is a direct request to the linker whereas `-pthread` is an option interpreted by the compiler driver.  If you use `-pthread` consistently at both compile and link time, that gives the compiler driver the opportunity to do anything _else_ that may be required, besides linking in libpthread, to make a multithread-capable program.  That said, I haven't tripped over a system where anything else was actually necessary in many years.

Comment: Hopefully moving forward we won't need to refer to pthreads at all, and a modern compiler will select the appropriate implementation of `<thread>` for our platform.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> `vector<thread> threads(1);`

This creates a thread which can be accessed at index `0`.

> `threads.push_back(thread([]{ cout << "Hello" << endl; }));`

This adds a second thread which can be accessed at index `1`.

> `for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), mem_fn(&thread::join));`

This is going to call `join` on both `thread` objects. However, the first one was never started therefore it is not joinable.

Instead, you could replace `vector<thread> threads(1);` with `vector<thread> threads; threads.reserve(1);` and keep using `push_back`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! This was exactly my problem. Instead of: `vector<thread> threads; threads.reserve(size);` I found this slightly more readable and self-explaining: `vector<thread> threads(size); threads.clear();` But I put a link to this post in a comment too.